# textarea resize: none is not working

Tags: css, textarea

I want the textarea to be not resizable, but I already tried all the possibilities: putting a class, id, or name in the textarea then setting its CSS to `resize: none`, but it still won't work. It is still resizable.

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: It should work.. See example: https://jsfiddle.net/02un5Lt6/
What browser do you use?

Comment: please provide your complete html css or link to a codepen where you can show that this is not working.  See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Did you try to view the actual resize property of the textarea while it's running? It might be that there's another stylesheet that overrides the resizable property of your textarea.

Comment: I experienced the same problem with Chrome when I ran the example at https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_form_textarea.

Answer (score 1):

i know this post is old, but if anyone else has this problem like i had too try this:

```
textarea{resize: none !important;}
```

Comment: That is a sign that you're either writing a very bad CSS OR you're using a library that you have to overwrite.